Enable a flutter Tooltip widget when scoped inside a disabled TextField InputDecoration
I have a TextField widget within a Form widget, and the TextField has a Tooltip widget within its decoration.
...surrounding input field redacted...

decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: 'Date Carried Out',
  suffixIcon: const Tooltip(
    message: 'Tooltip message',
    child: Icon(Icons.info,),
  ),                              
),


In some cases, the entire Form will be disabled (and hence it's constituent fields) - however, I required some tooltips to remain enabled such that the user can still discover the meaning of the field data being displayed.
Is there an allowance in the flutter widgets for this? If not, can it still be achieved?
Thank you

has a tooltip to be activated by a suffixIcon?

If making a TextField disabled completely disables its children like (prefix and suffix) Icons.
Then you can think of it out of box. by Putting a suffix icon directly above the TextField.
This ToolTip (suffix icon) will be enabled whatever the state of the text field.
Here's the pseudo code for that:
Stack(
 children:[
  
   YourTF(),
   Positined(

   top : 10,
   right : 10,
   child: ToolTip()

    ),
  ]
)

Hope it helps you.

I didn't quite understand, but it seems you have a tooltip in a TextField inside a Form and you want to keep tooltips even if the form is disabled.
You can define a formKey as nullable and display the concerning tooltip following the formKey value
decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Date Carried Out",
      suffixIcon: (_formKey != null)
          ? const Tooltip(
              message: 'Tooltip message',
              child: Icon(Icons.info),
            )
          : null),


Hi @yaya - sorry I don't follow how your example helps, could you please elaborate?

What do you mean by the Form will be disabled?
As I said I don't understand correctly your question. Give more details
